# having jQuery UI framework in TWebBrowser in Delphi

Tags: jquery, delphi, jquery-ui, browser

I am working on an application, lots of the UI elements will be in a TWebBrowser. So I thought I add a jQuery UI to make it easy for me.

I was able to insert JQuery and UI javascript file thanks to
http://www.jasontpenny.com/blog/2008/11/21/jquery-in-a-twebbrowser-in-a-self-contained-delphi-app/

I am stuck at stylesheets, I did

```
  doc2 := Web.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  doc2.createStyleSheet(FileProtocol(AppPath( 'templates\css\' + JQueryUITheme + '\jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css')), 0);
  // FileProtocol and AppPath are to return a current application path and converted to FileProtocol URL format.
```

the Javascripts ran fine, but I unable to get the images to work. I also tried to StringReplace all images references, but no result.

```
 stylesheet.cssText := StringReplace(stylesheet.cssText,
    'url(images/','url(' + FileProtocol(AppPath('templates/css/' +
    JQueryUITheme + '/images/')), [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running a quick test, this seems to work.

Are you sure FileProtocol() and AppPath() are working as they should?

these seem to work for me:

```
function FileProtocol(const s: String): String;
begin
   Result := 'file:///' + StringReplace(s, '\', '/', [rfReplaceAll]); // '
end;

function AppPath(const s: String): String;
begin
   Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter( ExtractFilePath(Forms.Application.ExeName) ) + s;
end;
```

**[Update]**

I downloaded JQuery UI from the homepage download link [[Current (stable)](http://jqueryui.com/download/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.zip)], and got the animated image from http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated

See demo project on GitHub: http://github.com/jasonpenny/democode/tree/057f0ad22fc5c3272909de346b6e67b0444d8981/JQueryUIProgBar

Comment: Odd, I am still not able to get the images to show up, when I call $().progressbar function from my Delphi app, I can only see the  div box change colour, but not the progressbar image.

How did you insert the stylesheet? createStyleSheet right?

Comment: I noticed in my demo that the order was important, I needed to add the background-image style to a later stylesheet (createStyleSheet()'s second parameter)

Comment: I just found graphics on the buttons are working fine with my existing code. :), not sure why the progressbar isn't working. Anyway, I used another progressbar plugin, which works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Does your HTML have a `<base href="" />` tag? Since it looks like relative paths are bust.

Answer (score -1):

Visit CGDevTools they have a jQuery components suite to use with Intraweb.